# How to stop Google Colab from automatically disconnecting from google drive?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I purchased Colab Pro+ in order to run my neural network notebooks overnight. I read and write files from my google drive by mounting it in the standard way:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

However, after a few hours, in the middle of training for seemingly no reason, the colab notebook inevitably disconnects from my mounted google drive, halting training with the following error:

`OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected`

Then the notebook just sits there for hours idly wasting my credits until it finally automatically disconnects the runtime.

This effectively means I cannot run my notebooks overnight which is the whole reason I purchased Colab Pro+. When I used Pro+ last year it did not have this issue and would stay connected to the google drive all night. Is this a known current issue?

Answer (score 3):

Google Colab does have some limitations due to its design as a shared resource, and one of those is that it can sometimes disconnect when left idle, or after a certain amount of usage time. However, the issue you are encountering where it disconnects from Google Drive even when a script is actively running seems unusual.

Here are some general suggestions to avoid disconnection issues:

1. **Keep your session active:** Even though this should not be necessary when a script is actively running, you could use a JavaScript code snippet that will press the Colab connect button for you every few minutes. It's not an ideal solution but has been reported to help some users. Please remember this might be against the terms of service, use with caution.

```js
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Working");
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

You should open the browser's developer tools (usually `F12`), go to the `Console` tab, paste the above script and hit `Enter`.

2. **Force reconnection to Google Drive:** You might consider adding a small routine to your script that checks whether the Google Drive connection is alive and if not, reconnects. Here is a rough example:

```py
import os

def check_and_reconnect_drive():
    try:
        # Check if Google Drive is still connected
        os.listdir('/content/drive')
    except:
        # If not, reconnect it
        from google.colab import drive
        drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)

# Then call this function every so often in your main script
check_and_reconnect_drive()
```

3. **Check on Google's Support or Forums:** As your issue seems unusual, it might be worth reaching out to Google's support or checking their forums to see if anyone else has reported the issue. It could be a bug or issue on their end that they can fix.

Remember, these are just possible workarounds and might not solve your issue permanently. For the ultimate stability, you may want to consider setting up your own cloud machine on services like AWS or GCP. It's a bit more complicated than using Colab, but it gives you complete control over your environment.